# How to find and replace text in object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an object looks like this: [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/DMw2EEqH) and I want to find every "a" and replace with underlined "a". I tried like : 
`preg_replace("/(" . preg_quote("a") . ")/", "<u>$1</u>", $object);`
 But it returns me a string not an object or array. How can I do it?

Comment: [*preg_replace() returns an array if the subject parameter is an array, or a string otherwise.*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) -- You are passing a JSON string, so you get a string back.

Comment: how can I change it?

Comment: What do you mean *change it*? What are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have a JSON string. What you have will work, but could have you inserting `<u>` tags into JSON keys, which you don't want.

How about first converting this JSON into an array, looping through the array, and updating each element with values that have had `a`s replaced:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($arr as &$elm){
    $elm = array_map(function($i){
        return preg_replace("/(" . preg_quote("a") . ")/", "<u>$1</u>", $i);
    }, $elm);
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/226107)

Comment: If the variable comes from outside your `array_map()` function, you'll need to use it. `array_map(function($i) use ($var){ .. },$a)`